# SwiftUI handling button/view with onTapGesture and onLongPressGesture with a release action

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, gesture

I have a view that has both onTapGesture and onLongPressGesture simultaneously. The issue is that the implementation of my onLongPressGesture prevents onTapGesture from ever being called.

Here is some code

```
View()
      .onTapGesture {
           action_1
       }
      .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 10, pressing: {
                                    pressing in
                                    self.isPressing = pressing
                                    if (pressing) {action_2}
                                    if !pressing {action_3}
                                }, perform: {})
```

The pressing argument in .onLongPressGesture detects if a user is pressing the view/button, and will always perform the .onLongPressGesture, regardless of what the minimumDuration is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

> Snapchat shutter where you can **tap** to take a picture, **hold** the button to start recording a video, then **release** the button to stop recording the video. That is why there are three actions that need to be performed.

This is tricky. Here's what I did:

1. `onTapGesture`, for the tap gesture
2. `LongPressGesture`, for a 0.5 second delay. Once the 0.5 seconds is over (`.onEnded`), start the recording.
3. `DragGesture`, for observing when the finger lift off the screen. When this happens, stop the recording.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    /// for visual indicators
    @State var recording = false
    @State var tapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        let longPressDrag = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) /// 2.
            .onEnded { _ in /// 0.5 seconds is over, start recording
                print("Long press start")
                recording = true
            }
            .sequenced(before: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)) /// 3.
            .onEnded { _ in /// finger lifted, stop recording
                print("Long press release")
                recording = false
            }
        
        Circle()
            .fill(recording ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .opacity(tapped ? 0.5 : 1)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            .onTapGesture { /// 1.
                print("Tapped")
                
                tapped = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { tapped = false }
            }
            .gesture(longPressDrag)

    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Snapchat-style button]

---

**Old answer:** The `pressing` parameter isn't for performing actions like `action_2`. You can, but it's more commonly used for changing `@State`, so for example highlighting the view in green when it's pressed. You can find more information in the [community documentation](https://swiftontap.com/view/onlongpressgesture(minimumduration:maximumdistance:pressing:perform:)).

Instead, what you probably want is to call your action (`action_2`/`print("long")`) in the `perform` closure.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
            .font(.title)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tap")
            }
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 10) {
                print("long")
            }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Both tap and long press work]

Comment: The only issue is that I want an action to be done when I start a long tap, and start another action when the long tap is released, this answer wouldn't work for that use-case.

Comment: @BestFromAbove got it. Will edit my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: an example to help you understand would be the Snapchat shutter where you can tap to take a picture, hold the button to start recording a video, then release the button to stop recording the video. That is why there are three actions that need to be performed.

Comment: I will try implementing it right now, I appreciate the effort to get a solution!

Comment: Great workaround! This will be the official answer until there is a more official way of handling these events! I appreciate the assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 14. Swift 5** I have added both gesture to Image View. On tap gesture image will be scale and unscale. On LongPressGesture image bg color will change. Provide count: 2 to make it doubleTapGesture.

```
struct ContentView: View {
// MARK: - Property

@State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
@State private var imageScale: CGFloat = 1
@State private var shadowColor: Color = .black

// MARK: - Content
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Image("magazine-front-cover")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding()
                .shadow(color: shadowColor, radius: 22, x: 2, y: 2)
                .opacity(isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: isAnimating)
                .scaleEffect(imageScale)
            // MARK: - 1. Tap Gesture
                .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                    if imageScale == 1 {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            imageScale = 5
                        }
                    } else {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            imageScale = 1
                        }
                    }
                })
            // MARK: - 2. LongPress Gesture
                .onLongPressGesture(perform: {
                    if shadowColor == .black {
                        shadowColor = .green
                    } else {
                        shadowColor = .black
                    }
                })
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
        .navigationTitle("Pinch & Zoom")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
                isAnimating = true
        }
    } // END of Navigation View
  }
}
```

[image]