# How to use both the Button action and onTapGesture for SwiftUI buttons?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I am new to swiftui and am trying to make use of both the Button action and the onTapGesture modifier (don't know if it is possible). But nothing I write in the .onTapGesture block is being run. Due to this the state of the @State variable beginNow is not being changed and the rectangle is never displayed. Please suggest a fix to use both Button action and .onTapGesture

```
            VStack {
                if beginNow{
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        tapped = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Let's Begin!")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                    })
                    
                    .scaleEffect(tapped ? 0 : 2)
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1), value: tapped)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        beginNow = true
                    }
                }
}
```

I have already tried using an extra boolean variable to differentiate the actions but it didn't work. Anything in the .onTapGesture block is just not executed.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638907/swiftui-handling-button-view-with-ontapgesture-and-onlongpressgesture-with-a-rel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work you need something to be picking up the tap outside the button. I have provided some code below that sets the VStack frame size and a background colour so you can see it. The second tap recogniser is also moved to the VStack. This provides an item that can accept the tap on and will pick up taps outside the button. There is also a logic check as you can see it will pick up taps before the button is pressed.

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var beginNow: Bool = false
@State var tapped: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if beginNow {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        } else {
            Button(action: {
                tapped = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Let's Begin!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
            })
            
            .scaleEffect(tapped ? 0 : 2)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1), value: tapped)
            .onTapGesture {
                beginNow = true
            }
        }
    }.frame(width: 300 , height: 500) // <----- providing some size or an item to accept the tap
        .background(Color.red)
        .onTapGesture {
            if tapped == true {
                beginNow = true
                print("Has begun")
            } else {
                print("Tapped but has not begun")
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks... this works except that it is not possible to set a frame size for the stack itself so instead a rectangle could be used with low opacity

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `onTapGesture` attached to a `Button` but you can change both variables in action closure like so:

```
Button(
    action: {
        tapped = true
        beginNow = true
    },
    label: {
        Text("Let's Begin!")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
)
.scaleEffect(tapped ? 0 : 2)
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 1), value: tapped)
```

Comment: ah yes I tried that but with that the scaleEffect animation for the button is not executed because the state is immediately reset